# Puppeteer freezing w/ multiple URLs, & skip any URL that times out and move to the next in my list

Tags: puppeteer

I have a Puppeteer script where it iterates through a list of URLs saved in urls.txt to scrape. I have 2 issues:

1. If one of the URLs in the list times out, it stops the whole process. I would like it to skip any URLS that don't work / timeout, and just move on to the next URL. I have tried to put in a catch(err), but I'm not putting it in correctly and it fails.
2. If the list of URLs is more than about 5, it freezes my server and I have to reboot. I think maybe it's waiting to iterate through all the URLs before saving and that's overloading the server? Or is there something else in my code that is causing the problem?

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');

process.setMaxListeners(Infinity); // <== Important line

async function scrapePage(url, index) {
  // Launch a new browser
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox'] });

  // Open a new page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Set the user agent
  await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');

  // Navigate to the desired webpage
  await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  });

  // Wait for selector
  await (async () => {
    await page.waitForSelector("#root > section > section > main > div.py-6.container > div.columns.mt-4 > div.column.is-flex-grow-2 > div:nth-child(3) > div.ant-card-body > div > div > div > canvas", { visible: true });
  })();

  // Get the HTML content of the page
  const html = await page.content();

  // Generate the file name using the index value
  const htmlFileName = `${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.html`;
  const screenshotFileName = `${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.png`;

  // Check if the HTML file exists
  const filePath = '/root/Dropbox/scrapes/' + htmlFileName;
  if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    // If the file exists, rewrite the content with the new scraped HTML
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, html);
  } else {
    // If the file doesn't exist, create the file
    fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(filePath, 'w'));

    // Save the scraped content to the newly created file
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, html);
  }

  // Capture a screenshot of the page
  await page.screenshot({ path: '/root/scrapes/' + screenshotFileName });


  // Close the browser
  await browser.close();
} 

// Read the lines of the file
const lines = fs.readFileSync('/root/Dropbox/urls.txt', 'utf-8').split('\n');

// Iterate through each URL in the file
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  // Scrape the page
  scrapePage(lines[i], i + 1);
}
```

Comment: Since you're in an async closure you might as well use async version of `fs` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Url's opening/closing too quickly and not waiting is probably the problem that you have while iterating through the urls, changing `scrapePage(lines[i], i + 1);` to `await scrapePage(lines[i], i + 1);` should solve that. Also `page.waitForSelector` doesn't need to be in `(async () => {..}`, the way you have it in your code.

To check if the URL's work or not you need to get the response from the `page.goto()` if that is 200 *(HTTP status code)* it means ok. On `try...catch`, take a look at the code below.

urls.txt - *random urls to test the code - stackover5flow is there to get an error*

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75911774/error-during-ssl-handshake-with-remote-server-node-js-with-apache
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75911761/unit-tests-of-private-function-in-javascript
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75911767/is-r-language-more-simplified-to-use-than-sql
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75911766/is-there-an-equivalent-of-term-variable-on-windows
https://stackover5flow.com/questions/75911176/puppeteer-timeout-30000ms-when-headless-is-true
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909981/how-can-i-elevate-the-privileges-of-an-executable-using-setuid-on-mac
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75911746/function-that-returns-an-array-of-4-int-taking-the-values-0-or-1-and-that-rando
```

code :

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;

process.setMaxListeners(Infinity); // <== Important line

let browser;
(async () => {

async function scrapePage(url, index, timeout = false) { // Launch a new browser
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // Set the user agent
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36');

    try {
        let res = await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded", timeout: 20000});
        res = res.status();
        
        if (res == 200) { // test if url can connect or not
            let selector = (timeout) ? "body[class=potato]" : "div.container"; // just to test timeout

            await page.waitForSelector(selector, {visible: true, timeout : 5000}); // timeout set to 5 secs, change if required
            const html = await page.content();
            const htmlFileName = `${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.html`;
            const screenshotFileName = `${index.toString().padStart(4, '0')}.png`;

            const dir = 'test/scrapes';
            const filePath = `${dir}/${htmlFileName}`;
            const screenshotPath = `${dir}/${screenshotFileName}`;

            await fsp.mkdir(dir, { recursive: true }, (e) => { if (e) console.log(e);}); // chk dir, if doesn't exist create
            await fsp.writeFile(filePath, html, { flag: 'w+' }, (e) => { if (e) throw e;}); // write/overwrite or throw error will stop script
            
            await page.screenshot({ path: screenshotPath});

        } else {
            console.log (res); 
        }

    } catch (e) { // this will catch any timeout or connection error
        console.log(e.message); 
    }
    
    await browser.close();
}

// Read
const lines = (await fsp.readFile('urls.txt', 'utf8')).split('\n');

for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {  
    let timeout =  (i == 1) ? true : false; // just to generate a timeout
    await scrapePage(lines[i], i + 1, timeout);
}

})().catch(err => console.error(err)). finally(() => browser ?. close());
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyVaM.jpg) : so it will give errors but will run unless that error is while writing/overwriting the files.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved both problems.