# function that returns an array of 4 int taking the values ​0 or 1 and that randomly returns one 1, then two 1s, then three 1s

Tags: c

I want to create an array of type `int` with 4 elements. Each element consists of `1` or `0`.
I'm trying to find a solution for my array has only a single randomly placed `1`, then two, then three.

I made this function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *tableauDeLed()
{
    static int tableau[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        tableau[i] = (rand() % 2);
    }
    return tableau;
}

int main()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        int *tableau = tableauDeLed();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            printf("%d, ",tableau[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result gives me a series of `1` or `0`. I can't find a function that will give me:

- a single one and zeroes (`0,1,0,0` for example) ;
- or 2 ones and zeroes (`0,1,0,1` for example) ;
- or 3 ones and zeroes. (`1,1,1,0` for example).

In fact I'm looking to make a function that will generate random series in one of these formats (perhaps that would take the desired number of `1` as parameters).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's an idea for 'n' 1's. Start by using the `for` loop to set every index of `tableau` to 0. Then have a counter like `int k=0;`. Use a `while` loop with a condition like `k<n`. In the body of the while loop, choose a random index in the tableau (so 0, 1, 2, or 3). If that index already contains a 1 then do nothing (maybe use `continue`). Otherwise set that index to 1 and increment k. You'll need to be careful about asking for too many 1's. This idea works ok for sparse numbers of n, but you would want to do something different for large dense arrays.

Comment: An efficient way to do this is: Let p be the remaining number of 1s desired. Let q be the total number of array entries. For i from 0 to q−1: With probability  p/(q-i), set tableau[i] to 1 and decrement p. Otherwise, set tableau[i] to 0 and do not change p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to set the number of `1` but store them at random places, also avoiding the use of `static` local objects:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *tableauDeLed(int *tableau, int size, int ones) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        tableau[i] = i < ones;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int pos = rand() % size;
        int tmp = tableau[pos];
        tableau[pos] = tableau[i];
        tableau[i] = tmp;
    }
    return tableau;
}

#define TABLE_COUNT  4

int main(void) {
    int table[TABLE_COUNT];
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        int *tableau = tableauDeLed(table, TABLE_COUNT, 1 + y % TABLE_COUNT);
        printf("%d", tableau[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < TABLE_COUNT; i++)
            printf(", %d", tableau[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0, 0, 1, 0
1, 0, 0, 1
1, 1, 0, 1
1, 1, 1, 1
1, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 1, 0
1, 1, 1, 0
1, 1, 1, 1
1, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 1, 1
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it.